# What is the name of non-neural network algorithms

Tags: algorithms

i am writing papers for my academic degree on machine learning.

everytime I get confused when I try to put a name for standard algorithms (KNN, Linear Regression, Random Forest, etc) ( the non-neural network algorithms)

are they called standard algorithms?

or classic algorithms?

or generic algorithms?

is there a name that is used for these kind of algorithms?

Comment: Good question, I don't know if there's a commonly accepted term. I think I've seen "statistical ML methods" as opposed to DL methods. I often say "traditional ML methods" or "standard ML methods" but I'm not sure it's very good.